# Windows server- disk management and diskpart show different disk sizes

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2012, disk-space

I have an HB proliant server with windows server 2012 R2 as OS. it has already 4Tb disk that drive `c` and `D` are on it. recently we added a bay with 8 disk all together are 8 TB. i wanted to format and assign this newly added disk then i realize that in disk management it shows:

```
   disk 0 : 4471 GB
   disk 1 : 14531 GB
```

then i ran powershell and in `diskpart` after `list disk` i have this:

```
   disk 0 : 4471 GB
   disk 1 : 7734 GB
```

why this happens and how i can fix it?

edit: rebooting the server does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
diskmgmt.msc
```

Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run the above command it will show details about the available disk and partitions.

Comment: yes this is the disk management i mentioned in my question. it shows 14 TB. but in powershell it shows 7 TB.